# Unable to load product details page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make a product detail page. So when users are on the products page they can click on a specific product to see the details of the products but I'm getting some errors.

This is the all products view page where I'm loading all my products:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details">
            <?php  echo '<img src="upload/'.$product['product_foto'].'">' ; ?>
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the product detail controller function:

```
public function details($product_id) {
     //vraag product details
     $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);

     //laad view
     $data['main_content'] = 'details';
     $this->load->view('details',$data);
 }
```

This is the product detail view page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div><?php echo $product->product_naam; ?></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url().'upload/'.$product['product_foto'] ?>" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the product detail model function:

```
public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('id', $product_id);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
```

When I try to load a detail page of a product I'm getting these errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Product::details()

Filename: controllers/Product.php

Line Number: 18

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 18
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once



A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Product::$Product_model

Filename: controllers/Product.php

Line Number: 20

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 20
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once





A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function get_cadeau_details() on a non-object

Filename: controllers/Product.php

Line Number: 20

Backtrace:
```

When I type: `<?php echo "<pre>";print_r($products);echo "</pre>";?>`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 29
            [product_naam] => bfbfbf
            [product_beschrijving] => fdeed
            [user_id] => 0
            [product_categorie] => eetbaar
            [ophaal_plaats] => fbfg
            [product_foto] => 78fa40277b5b961b7b3c3c25e4f5a2af.jpg
            [date_created] => 2017-07-12
            [date_updated] => 2017-07-12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 30
            [product_naam] => dfbfg
            [product_beschrijving] => fdgfgfg
            [user_id] => 0
            [product_categorie] => kleding
            [ophaal_plaats] => gfgdgf
            [product_foto] => fdbf476783f74afef45ecd84a8df0da1.jpg
            [date_created] => 2017-07-12
            [date_updated] => 2017-07-12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 31
            [product_naam] => Call of duty BO III
            [product_beschrijving] => fefef
            [user_id] => 0
            [product_categorie] => kec
            [ophaal_plaats] => Japan
            [product_foto] => 66e57b903b9d297c575259b3dfb04f70.jpg
            [date_created] => 2017-07-12
            [date_updated] => 2017-07-12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 32
            [product_naam] => fefe
            [product_beschrijving] => gwrfef
            [user_id] => 0
            [product_categorie] => spellen
            [ophaal_plaats] => efefef
            [product_foto] => b8c923e48baa25d363baa29da40e23e1.jpg
            [date_created] => 2017-07-12
            [date_updated] => 2017-07-12
        )

)
```

Comment: The error is very clear $product_id missing,  add $product['product_id'] to the link tag. your controller function details() needs to read product_id paramter.

Comment: Where do i put $product_id?

Comment: Here you see the a href, just beside the Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id'];?> and you are done.<div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details">
            <?php  echo '<img src="upload/'.$product['product_foto'].'">' ; ?>
        </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your view code (Same as the above answer):
And Please make sure that the "$products" contains key named as "id" in it.

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
            <?php  echo '<img src="upload/'.$product['product_foto'].'">' ; ?>
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And then in the controller change in the following way:

```
public function details() {  //Remove product id from arguments
     $product_id = $this->uri->segment('3');
     $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);
     $data['main_content'] = 'details';
     $this->load->view('details',$data);
 }
```

And please note that you have to load the URL helper,in case you get error:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Hello, I tried you're code and I'm getting some errors. The first error is when I open all products I see this error on every product: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: id

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 47

Backtrace:

Comment: Also I'm getting this error when I click on a product: An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: please put the code above foreach and see what you are getting : <?php echo "<pre>";print_r($products);echo "</pre>";?>

Comment: Hey I added that piece of code and I'm editing my answer so you can see what I'm getting.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can see what I'm getting when I type: <?php echo "<pre>";print_r($products);echo "</pre>";?>

Comment: i have edited the code actually the "id" was not supplied so changed it to "product_id".Check the code for view file .Specially this line --><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">

Comment: Ok now I can see my products again but I still get these errors when I click on a product: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Product::$Product_model

Filename: controllers/Product.php

Line Number: 20

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 20
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: And this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function get_product_details() on a non-object

Filename: controllers/Product.php

Line Number: 20

Backtrace:

Comment: Have you loaded this model "Product_model" ?

Comment: Yes sir I'm loading my model like this:  public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('product_model');
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 }

Comment: Or do I need to load my model in the details function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149097/discussion-between-ketan-solanki-and-lablanco).

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Problem is you are calling your `details($productid)` methode wrongly. To solve this, in your all product page add product id in `<a>` tag. see code below .

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
            <?php  echo '<img src="upload/'.$product['product_foto'].'">' ; ?>
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: getting this error now: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: id

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 47

Comment: and this error when I click on a product: An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.